# Using Fiddler2 to trace HTTPS SharePoint Calls

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2010, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler2 to trace the https sharepoint calls. After starting the fiddler and browisng the https site it throws the error:

Access Denied (connect_method_denied):
....
This is typically caused by an HTTPS URL that uses a port other then the default of 443.

Any suggestion to resolve the issue will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Mac

Comment: Well, ARE you using a different port for your HTTPS connection than 443? You could try different monitoring applications like Microsoft's netmon, Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

That message is coming from your upstream proxy server. The question is why you're not seeing it in IE itself. Try disabling proxy chaining inside Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections and see if that helps.